# What is the right way to implement a function which returns the value being set to false in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a function which, on update of any attribute of a model, sets the status of  `is_kyc_verified` to false.

Here is the code of the User model and the method which changes the status:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  before_update :change_kyc_status, unless: :is_kyc_verified_changed?

  #Associations
  has_one  :address, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :kyc, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :pan_detail, dependent: :destroy
  has_one  :document, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :nominee_details, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bank_details, dependent: :destroy

  #Accept Attributes for associated model

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :kyc, :pan_detail,
                                :document, :nominee_details, :bank_details,
                                allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank


  #validates
  validates :name, :mobile_no, :gender, :dob,  presence: true
  validates :mobile_no, numericality: true, length: { is: 10 }

  private
  ##
  # Check if is_kyc_verified is set to true
  # if 'yes' then alert user and set is_kyc_verified to false
  def change_kyc_status
    self.is_kyc_verified = false if self.valid? and self.is_kyc_verified.present?
    true
  end

end
```

The method initially used to return the `self.is_kyc_verified`, which was false, in turn resulted in "rollback of transaction".  I explicitly added a true at the end so it won't rollback the transaction.

However I feel that this is not the right way to implement this function.
Can you please review my code and suggest the right way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

What is the underlying purpose of `is_kyc_verified`? Is there a reason you actually need to return true or false? It seems like return alone would do the trick:

```
 def change_kyc_status
    is_kyc_verified = (valid? && is_kyc_verified.present?) ? false : true
    return
 end
```

Comment: `is_kyc_verified` is flag which indicates that the customer has verified his know your customer details. but if he edits his personal information again i.e after he is being verified  then he has to re-verify his details hence I need to set `is_kyc_verified` to false if he updates any info.

Comment: BTW in your solution too `return` is used otherwise it will return `false`.